# DJANGO: Product matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHh7R.png)

I don’t understand what’s the matter. I do everything exactly according to the courses, but knocks out an error:
**Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/basket-add/12/ Django Version: 3.2.4 Exception Type: DoesNotExist Exception Value:
Product matching query does not exist.**

Add object:

```
def basket_add(request, product_id):
    current_page = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    baskets = Basket.objects.filter(user=request.user, product=product)

    if not baskets.exists():
        Basket.objects.create(user=request.user, product=product, quantity=1)
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(current_page)
    else:
        basket = baskets.first()
        basket.quantity += 1
        basket.save()
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(current_page)
```

Delete:

```
def basket_delete(request, id):
    basket = Basket.objects.get(id=id)
    basket.delete()
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

template:

```
<a href="{% url 'products:basket_delete' basket.id %}" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">
   <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
</a>
```

URLs:

```
from django.urls import path
from products.views import products, basket_add, basket_delete

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', products, name="index"),
    path('basket-add/<int:product_id>/', basket_add, name="basket_add"),
    path('basket-add/<int:id>/', basket_delete, name="basket_delete"),
]
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import User

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Product Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}  ({self.category.name})"


class Basket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Basket for {self.user.username} | Product {self.product.name}"
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkAGD.jpg)
[Database2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5gv7.jpg)

**On version 3.2.4, Django throws this error, on 2.8 it throws it to another page (and not the current one) and sometimes adds a new item to the cart and never removes it from it. I saw the advice to use get_or_404, but it won't fix the error.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two url patterns that *completely* overlap. This means that it will trigger the first view in case you call that view.

You thus should make url patterns that do not *completely* overlap, and preferrably do not overlap at all, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', products, name="index"),
    path('basket-add/<int:product_id>/', basket_add, name="basket_add"),
    path('basket-delete/<int:id>/', basket_delete, name="basket_delete")
]
```

so for the second path, we replaced `basket-add/` with `basket-delete/`.

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the deletion works fine, but when you add the same product, the quantity is not added to the cart .. Also, when you delete it from the cart, it is no longer possible to add it again.

Comment: @execution: your logic removes the cart itself, not removes the product from the cart.

Comment: @execution: please do not add *permanent* redirects, but simple redirects. Otherwise the browser will skip adding the next time. You likely should also clear the browser cache, such that the browser starts making requests again.